# xamarin mutli selection listview

Tags: android, listview, xamarin, listviewitem

It's been a while that i'm trying to get an anwser to my problem, but i didn't find it... So i'm searching for your help.

I work on xamarin to make an android application but i dont use Xamarin.Forms (i would have used it, if i knew it when i begin the project

I'll directly to the point, if you have some question, just ask me.

So i got a Listview where i can select 2 or more items :

```
private void _listViewIntervention_ItemClick(object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        _intervention[e.Position].IsSelected = !_intervention[e.Position].IsSelected;
        if (_intervention[e.Position].IsSelected)
            e.View.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(255, 127, 127));
        else
            e.View.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Rgb(230, 230, 230));

        _numberInterventionSelected.Text = _intervention.FindAll(elem => elem.IsSelected == true).Count().ToString();
    }
```

That thing work but if i have a listview with 20 items i.e and i select 3 items, if i scroll the listview, everything will be disturb and my 3 highlighted rows won't be anymore and the highlight will be on another row that i've never select.

I think that not that evident and it might be blur.

IMO i'm not changing the good thing when i do the "e.View.SetBackgroundColor" but i've try lot of thing that never worked.
I might not going the best way to do what i want to do btw.

The result i want is when i scroll the listview, nothing change so i can select the first and the last item of the listview i.e.

I search again in my side but i count a little on you know...
Thanks for reading and have a good day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already getting same problem after lot of search and find the solution

In Xamarin custom adapter remove ViewHolder System it's working fine after removing Holder system

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick anwser ! 
I've tried to find the ViewHolder System but i didn't find it..
In which file do you think it might be, because in the class of my adapter i didn't use ViewHolder. 
So is that a thing that is auto-setup and that you need to remove ?
Thanks

Comment: After reading you comment i try to find an anwser in the custom adapter, and i find it ! know it's working fine, i means it does what i wanted (maybe not in a good way to dev...). Now i got a new problem but less harder that the first one, it's simply when i adapt, the scroll automatically go up to the top instead of staying where i was in the scroll. Do you have an idear how to remove that ? I will search to my side

Comment: ok good if you found solution you will search for that 

please up vote the answer

Comment: Thanks for the anwser !