# When I chose one item in ListView in Xamarin Android is choosen twin

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

When I chose one item in ListView in Xamarin Android is choosen twins . In Xamarin.Forms exist setting the Caching Strategy of ListView : RetainElement
and  RecycleElement .

С#

`var listView = new ListView(ListViewCachingStrategy.RecycleElement);`

XAML

```
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
          ...
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

How can I config cache in the Xamarin Android ? Cause I have are problem , when I choose some Items in the ListView it's choosen twice symmetric in another part of ListView . What I must to do to fix that ? Say me please somebody ! Than You !

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more or post an image to describe your problem.

Comment: **York Shen - MSFT** Imagine ListView in the screen . I touch first item and he is change background . I scroll down and I have one more selected and when I choose more items I get symmetric choosen items in another part of ListView. 
 Problem is in RecycleView . I think indexes is repeat . For example if I choose in the programm in the adapter an item he is work correct . But when I choose in List<string> item ,which is in the adapter , I get wrong item often . How can I work with RecycleView , or maybe to off him ?

Comment: Your code in the question is Xamarin.Forms, but RecycleView is belong to native android, what is your project type? Xamarin.Forms or Xamarin.Android?

Comment: Xamarin Android but I thought it same structure. So if not I dont know in what is problem.

Comment: Please post your Xamarin.Android ListView code.

Comment: I'm sorry but my code is not wrong . Problem is in the caching ListView and get List<> inside his adapter are index . It's impossible that nobody meet this .

Comment: If we can't see your code, we can't find the problem.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT Can explain me please what ViewHolder System is in this post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806583/xamarin-mutli-selection-listview?rq=1) ? And please say me , you said that RecycleView is only in Xamarin.Forms  , but in this answer is code with RecyclerView and in the tags is Xamarin Android ,is are mistake ?

Comment: [ListView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/) in Xamarin.Forms, [RecyclerView](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/layouts/recycler-view/) in native Android.

Comment: Delete the `ListAdapter.Remove(contactList[e.Position])` will solve your problem.

Comment: Im sorry  
@YorkShen-MSFT will not resolve . I made `ListAdapter.Remove(contact List[in.Position])` to see are differences what we delete and what is in Console .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

recycling works like this: when you display your list, let's say there are 6  items displayed, then you will have a pool of at least 6 cell instances. When you scroll, the instances of the cells that disappeared "return" to the "unused" instances pool. This pool is used when the listview has to display a new cell, so that the existing instances get used again for other lines, with other content.

Please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14108676/2814072) for great explanation

Your issue seems to be that the cell (view instance) state changes when you click on a cell, and is not reset when reusing that instance.

You should keep a trace of the state of each cell's content and assign it when getting any cell. The [ViewHolder Pattern](https://dzone.com/articles/optimizing-your-listview) is a good way to manage it

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes of course ! Is very cool answer . Now I understand ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> contactList;
    ListView list;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
        var uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.ContentUri;
        string[] projection = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.Number, ContactsContract.Contacts.InterfaceConsts.DisplayName };
        var cursor = ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        contactList = new List<string>();
        if (cursor.MoveToFirst())
        {
            while (cursor.MoveToNext())
                contactList.Add(cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[0])) + cursor.GetString(cursor.GetColumnIndex(projection[1])));
        }
        var ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Resource.Layout.ContactItemView, contactList);
        list.Adapter = ListAdapter;

        list.ItemClick += (sender, e) => { ListAdapter.Remove(contactList[e.Position]); Console.WriteLine(ListAdapter.GetItem(e.Position)); };}
```