# Remove LinearLayout item on touch

Tags: android, xamarin, android-linearlayout

It posibile to delete special View in the LinearLayout onClick in Xamarin Android ? 
 For example I introduce in LinearLyout some TextView's and I touched one to delete . I can do this without Id of TextView , can I delet throught LinearLayout ? Logical scheme :

```
var layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout);
TextView text;
layout.Click += (sender, e) => {text = new TextView(this); text.Text="Text";    
layout.AddView(text) };


// And here I don't know how to make, something like this

layout.Click /*Click on text*/ += (sender,e) =  layout.Remove(/*OnTouched 
TextView in LinearLayout*/);
```

It is posibile ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `view.SetVisibility(ViewStates.Gone)` to remove a view from its parent's hierarchy, try doing that into the `Click` handler

edit after comment:

then you should add your Click method on each view instead of adding it to the layout:

```
text.Click /*Click on text*/ += (sender,e) =>
    sender.SetVisibility(ViewStates.Gone);
```

Comment: Yes you right , but I forgot to say what i have always new instance and I must get this TextView by arg. I fix code .

``

Comment: then you should add your Click method on each view instead of adding it to the layout:

`text.Click /*Click on text*/ += (sender,e) => sender.SetVisibility(ViewStates.Gone);`

Comment: Yes @AdricoM . I fixed code right now . Can you see now please ? 
I want to work with layout like an ListView . Something like this .

Comment: then you should try:

`var layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout);
TextView text;
layout.Click += (sender, e) => {text = new TextView(this); text.Text="Text";
 text.Click += (sender,e) => sender.SetVisibility(ViewStates.Gone);    
layout.AddView(text) };`

Comment: Somethink wrong . I can not work correct with args . Work's only like this but is deleted only last instance .
 `var layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.layout); 
TextView text; 
layout.Click += (sender, e) => {text = new TextView(this); text.Text="Text"; text.Click += (sender,e) => text.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone; layout.AddView(text) };`
 Args absolutely not work .

Comment: Only the last instance is deleted because each time you click on the layout you create a new view but you assign it to the same variable. If you need to keep a track of all the Textviews, consider using a list or an array

Comment: Ok . I hoped to use clear LinearLayout to delete TextView wich contains .
 Thank you @AdricoM !

Comment: @ AdricoM I hoped to work with LinearLayout cause I don't found are solution in my theme here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170106/when-i-chose-one-item-in-listview-in-xamarin-android-is-choosen-twin) , may be you can help ?

Comment: answered there, hope it will help

Comment: @ AdricoM Thank you !